# How do i stop http://builtwith.com/ and other services identifying my codeigniter site

Tags: codeigniter

How do i stop http://builtwith.com/ and other similar services from identifying my website as built with codeigniter? For security purposes i would like to hide it. I know the website is secure & tested.

Comment: Do you know what Builtwith's crawler's user agent is? You can block that. But also I would like to know what exactly is it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not using any of the default `ci_` prefixes for cookies/sessions. Anything prefixed with `ci_` will be a dead giveaway for a crawler that analyzes these things.

CodeIgniter doesn't send special headers that identify itself as far as I know, so that shouldn't be an issue.